# Do PostgreSQL CLI commands on Windows work?

Tags: postgresql, windows, command-line-interface, psql

Do PostgreSQL CLI commands on Windows work?

I'm trying basic command like `--version` or `-V` for PostgreSQL version info, but I can't get any result. I've tried multiple permutations, including:

- `--version` w/ or w/o semicolon
- `\--version` w/ or w/o semicolon
- `psql --version` w/ or w/o semicolon
- `\psql --version` w/ or w/o semicolon

I made sure that the PostgreSQL service is running.
Some commands work, for example `\l`.

Comment: `psql` and the Postgres server are two different things, where the former is a command line program for connecting to the latter. The version you get for `psql` may not  necessarily be the same as that of the server.

Comment: I'm following this freeCodeCamp.org "Learn PostgreSQL Tutorial - Full Course for Beginners". From 32nd minute he's using psql commands inside psql shell.

Answer (score 2):

If `\l` works, then you have already started `psql.exe` and thus you can only run SQL commands (that need to be terminated with `;`)  or meta commands that start with `\`

However there is no meta command to display the version of `psql.exe`, you can do that **only** from the Windows command line (`cmd.exe`)

```
c:\>psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 15.0

c:\>
```

But that only gives you the version of `psql.exe`, **not** the version of the Postgres *server*. If you want to find out the server version run the SQL command *inside* of `psql`:

```
c:\>psql postgres postgres
psql (15.0)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# select version();
                          version
------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 15.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
(1 row)


postgres=#
```

Comment: When psql and Postgres versions are different psql welcome message indicates this, e.g. `psql (15.0, server 14.3)`

Comment: Actually you can do it from in `psql` by temporarily shelling out: `\! psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.5`.